# Why does achocha have two types of leaves?

Tags: leaves

I was looking at my achocha plant, and noticed it has two types of leaves. Why is this?

Comment: Hi! Can you post a picture? Maybe it's leaf-shape polymorphism. Or maybe you're looking at cotyledon leaves?

Comment: i gave that plant to my church, and it was round. the next ones were the normal spikes though

Comment: Sounds interesting. Take a pic of it next time when you go to church. Maybe you'll atract an answer this way.